# ionic 2: while run in emulator it shows error but running in server it works

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

something really weird happened me after i just add some plugins in my app..
when i run

> ionic run serve

the app work find and i can get response from server
as you can see here
[image]

but where i run

> ionic run android

it show the spinner and shows error as you can see here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do http requests via an ionic app, you need to white list the urls. You can use [cordova whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin to do this.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

and in the index file

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *; object-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

this code was copied by the following tutorial, have a look at it.

http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-making-rest-http-requests-like-a-pro/

HTH